# Oracle regexp_replace to prevent semicolons

Tags: oracle, sql-injection, regexp-replace

Is the following code sufficient to prevent any semicolon from ever remaining in v_str?

```
regexp_replace(v_str, ';')
```

Or is there a way someone can circumvent it?

For example the following snippet is not sufficient to block 'DROP' from being passed:

```
regexp_replace(v_str, 'DROP')
```

Someone can bypass this by passing in 'DRDROPOP'.

Seemingly, however, the semicolon prevention above is sufficient. Can you think of a way to break it?

Comment: We are in the midst of refactoring it. However, at the moment, we need a quick fix - the above seems to catch all semicolons.

Comment: @Stick-With-SQL Beware "quick" fixes. In my experience, they often result in deprioritization of a proper fix. "It's working now. Why do we need to spend more time on it?"

Comment: Yep thanks - we're trying to push to get the entire approach recfactored

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will give you the desired result.  However, I think regular ole [REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) is probably more efficient than using the regex_* functions.

```
WITH t AS
 (SELECT ';1234;abcd;;5678;;;efgh;;' x
    FROM dual)
SELECT x,
       REPLACE(x,
               ';'),
       regexp_replace(x,
                      ';')
  FROM t;
```

As others have stated this is NOT a good solution for preventing SQL injection, but I understand your need for a stepping stone.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick temporary fix it can work, but it won't stop crafty users from pushing characters in your queries.

For instance :

```
'DROP DATABASE' || chr(59)
'DROP DATABASE' || chr(58+1)
...
```

Comment: The  chr(59) would be removed as well being that its resolved to a semicolon in v_str before being passed to the regexp_replace function.